# convert Csv file into Xml on Azure data lake store using Azure Powershell runbook

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-runbook

I  want to convert CSV file into XML on Azure data lake store using Azure **Powershell**.
I was using this code on **Runbook of azure automation**
and it worked fine but **No XML is being generated**

```
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'xyz'
$subscriptionName = 'Pay-As-You-Go'
$null = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName | Out-Null 
$adla = "TestAzure"
$obj = Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName $adla -Path "/custom/logile/masters/Test/Test.csv" 
 $xmlobj = ConvertTo-Xml -InputObject $obj -As 'string' 
$xmlobj | Out-File -FilePath "/custom/logile/masters/Test/xmlOut.xml"
```

This code is working fine till "$obj= Get" here, but I am not able to write into Azure data lake.
Is there any way that I can use Object to write the file in Azure data lake.

Comment: Why can't `Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem` be used to upload the file? What are the contents of `$obj` after the code runs?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Do you have write access to `/custom/logile/masters/Test/`?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for reaching out!

You were trying to export the xml file using Out-File cmdlet to an nonexistent path `/custom/logile/masters/Test` in current instance of the Azure Automation execution. And you were not uploading the xml file to a Data Lake Store.

To accomplish your requirement you would have to use the below commands by replacing last line in your runbook (i.e., last line is `$xmlobj | Out-File -FilePath "/custom/logile/masters/Test/xmlOut.xml"`)

```
$xmlobj | Out-File -FilePath "$env:temp/xmlOut.xml"
Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName $adla -Path "$env:temp/xmlOut.xml" -Destination "/custom/logile/masters/Test/xmlOut.xml"
```

I have tested it successfully. If interested you may check below screenshots for illustration.

[image: Shell power runbook]

[image: Test]

[image: Data Explorer]

Note that the first few lines of my runbook in the above screenshot are a bit different from yours because I have given Automation Account RunAs account the permission to Data Lake store destination folder. So you may ignore this part.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!